# Why is $z^T x \leq \|x\| \| z \|_*$ for dual norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is probably very obvious, I was looking at [this](https://wiki.sfu.ca/personal/aoberman/index.php/Norms_and_dual_norms#Inequality).

It looks so much like a Cauchy-Schwarz though, and I would say it is very obvious from the definition if it wasn't for the condition that $\|x\| \le 1$ in the definition:

$$\| z \| := \sup_x\{ z^T x : \|x\| \le 1\}.$$

How is that restriction still ok?

Comment: In a word, scaling.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

Using Robert Israel's hint, let $y = \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$. Note that $\|y\| = 1$ and $x = \|x\|y$, so we have

$$z^Tx = z^T(\|x\|y) = \|x\|(z^Ty) \leq \|x\|\sup_y\{z^Ty \mid \|y\| \leq 1\} = \|x\|\|z\|_*.$$